# Cannot find state property after ComponentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs

I want to practice my reactjs skills so I am doing some exercises with api calls to the popular openweathermap api

I am making the api call in the componentDidMount() cycle which following the documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html), is the better place to make the async call

If I console.log(data) in render I first get undefined then I get the object that I need; but if I try to access said object with {data.city.name} which does exist I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" on the second re-render (componentDidMount() forces a second render)

I do not know what I am missing, I am not that experienced with lifecycles but it is pretty straightforward, I do not understand why this is happening

Can anyone enlighten me please? Thank you.

```
import React from 'react';

class WeekForecast extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      data: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch([url]) 
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            data: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {        
    const { data } = this.state;   
    return(
      <div> 
        <p>This weeks forecast in {data.city.name}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default WeekForecast;
```

Comment: this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            data: result
          }, () => console.log(this.state.data));

Can you see the data this way?

Comment: <p>This weeks forecast in {data && data.city.name}</p>


(if data exists return data.city.name else do not return anything (null))

Comment: I think the response is returned in first then, but not a s a promise to resolve in the second then( where you are setting the state). Due to this, state.data will always be []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing this error because you are trying to get a property from an object which is `undefined`. If you try to log a property which is `undefined` at that time is not a problem, but if you try to get a property from this `undefined` object then you get an error.

```js
const  data = {};

console.log( "city is", data.city );
console.log( "city name is", data.city.name );
```

Here is another example. What if we don't define an empty object for `data`? You are defining one in your state, but what if we don't?

```js
//const  data = {};

console.log( "city is", data.city );
console.log( "city name is", data.city.name );
```

Here since `data` is not defined, we can't get the `city` as `undefined`.

In your situation, `data` is defined in your state as an empty object. So, trying to log the `city` returns an `undefined`, but trying to log `city.name` returns error.

Because your data is landing in your component after the first render you should check you have it with a conditional rendering. You will use this all the time when you are dealing with the data which is coming from a remote place. There are many ways doing the conditional rendering. Here is one of them:

```
renderHelper() {
  const { data } = this.state;
  if ( !data.city ) { return <p>Loading data...</p>}
  return <p>This weeks forecast in {data.city.name}</p>
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      { this.renderHelper() }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you, the loading idea completely skipped my mind

Answer (score 1):

Hope the below snippet helps.
Couple of issues.

1. The Promise handle was misused.
2. Handling the data on the firs render (data validation before operating).

```js
class WeekForecast extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      data: {}
    };
  }
  fetch = () => Promise.resolve({city:{name:"New York City"}})

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetch()
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            data: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {        
    const { data } = this.state;   
    return(
      <div> 
        <p>This weeks forecast in {data.city && data.city.name || 'No City'}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<WeekForecast />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Actually, `fetch` returns a `Promise` in the first `then` method. This is why we need to deal with this somehow like `.json()`.